# Collecting large amounts of data efficiently

Tags: python, physics, astronomy

I have a program that creates a solar system, integrates until a close encounter between adjacent planets occur (or until 10e+9 years), then writes two data points to a file. The try and except acts as a flag when planets get too close. This process is repeated 16,000 times. This is all being done by importing the module [REBOUND](http://rebound.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which is a software package that integrates the motion of particles under the influence of gravity.

```
for i in range(0,16000):
    def P_dist(p1, p2):
        x = sim.particles[p1].x - sim.particles[p2].x
        y = sim.particles[p1].y - sim.particles[p2].y
        z = sim.particles[p1].z - sim.particles[p2].z
        dist = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)
        return dist

    init_periods = [sim.particles[1].P,sim.particles[2].P,sim.particles[3].P,sim.particles[4].P,sim.particles[5].P]

    try:
        sim.integrate(10e+9*2*np.pi)
    except rebound.Encounter as error:
        print(error)
        print(sim.t)

    for j in range(len(init_periods)-1):
        distance = P_dist(j, j+1)
        print(j,":",j+1, '=', distance)
        if distance <= .01: #returns the period ratio of the two planets that had the close enecounter and the inner orbital period between the two
            p_r = init_periods[j+1]/init_periods[j]
            with open('good.txt', 'a') as data: #opens a file writing the x & y values for the graph
                data.write(str(math.log10(sim.t/init_periods[j])))
                data.write('\n')
                data.write(str(p_r))
                data.write('\n')
```

Whether or not there is a close encounter depends mostly on a random value I have assigned, and that random value also controls how long a simulation can run. For instance, I chose the random value to be a max of 9.99 and a close encounter happened at approximately 11e+8 years(approximately 14 hours). The random values range from 2-10, and close encounters happen more often on the lower side. Every iteration, if a close encounter occurs, my code will write to the file where I believe may be taking up a lot of simulation time. Since the majority of my simulation time is taken up by trying to locate close encounters, I'd like to shed some time by finding a way to collect the data needed without having to append to the file every iteration.

Since I'm attempting to plot the data collected from this simulation, would **creating two arrays and outputting data** into those be faster? Or is there a way to only have to **write to a file once**, when all 16000 iterations are complete?

`sim` is a variable holding all of the information about the solar system.

This is not the full code, I left out the part where I created the solar system.

```
count = 0
data = open('good.txt', 'a+')
....
     if distance <= .01:
         count+=1
         while(count<=4570)
             data.write(~~~~~~~)
....
data.close()
```

Comment: Your idea is correct, but the logic is wrong.  That while loop is infinite: `count` is 1 when you enter the loop, and it never changes.  You have only one loop, but two ways to exit: `j >= len(periods)` or `count > 4570`.  Either code both conditions into your loop header, or use the second one to `break` from the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't that you write every time you find a close encounter.  It's that, for each encounter, you open the file, write one output record, and close the file.  All the opening and appending is *slow*.  Try this, instead: open the file *once*, and do only *one* write per record.

```
# Near the top of the program
data = open('good.txt', 'a')
...
    if distance <= .01: #returns the period ratio of the two planets that had the close enecounter and the inner orbital period between the two
        # Write one output record
        p_r = init_periods[j+1]/init_periods[j]
        data.write(str(math.log10(sim.t/init_periods[j])) + '\n' +
                   str(p_r) + '\n')
...
data.close()
```

This should work well, as writes will get buffered, and will often run in parallel with the next computation.

Comment: Great, one more question. I've decided to decrease my sample size down to 4570 close encounters. Since close encounters don't occur every iteration, I've came up with a way to keep the program running until 4570 close encounters are met.

Comment: That's a statement, not a question.  Missing a word or two, perhaps?

Comment: In my most recent post edit, I've uploaded a block of code similar to yours. Is this an efficient way to get the amount of data I need?

Comment: Ah ... these comments need to be on the question then, not on this answer.